# How to add a project to the SVN?

Tags: svn

I am new for SVN and I need to add my project to SVN.I dont know how to create an Hostname for the project I need to add in SVN.

Please guy's help me to get knowledge about SVN.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How to create an svn repository?  How to make that repository accessible to others?

Comment: The following does not make any sense: "I dont know how to create an Hostname for the project I need to add in SVN" -- please rephrase.

Comment: @Cdhowie:Exactly Iwant to know the things what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Read the book on svn - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ to get started.
2. Check out the quick reference to keep a mental map of all the commands : http://www.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/SvnQuickReferenceCard.html

To get started, you could do the following. Read the details in the book.

- Create a repository

  - svnadmin create /svnrepos
- Create a user

  - vi /svnrepos/conf/svnserve.conf

    - anon-access = none
    - auth-access = write
    - password-db = passwd
- Add a password file

  - vi /svnrepos/conf/passwd

    - add users in the format : user = password
- Import your existing project

  - svn import /projects/myproject file:///svnrepos/myproject
- Start the server:

  - svnserve -d
- Try checking out:

  - svn co svn://localhost/svnrepos/myproject

Answer (score 0):

Use **svnadmin create**, then use **svn checkout** to get a copy of it.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re29.html